# Group objects in Blender using notepad file of objects to group

Tags: python, list, blender, bpy

I want to group some of the objects in a large Blender file.

I would like to list the objects to be grouped in a notepad file which is saved in the same location as the blender file.

Example test case would contain 6 Cubes. Cube1, Cube2 and Cube3 would be listed in a notepad file and once the script is run, they would be in a group called 'Group' while the remaining cube objects remain separate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: edited to remove second part of question

Comment: Does group mean a collection?